# Extension in iOS8 - Terminating since there is no system app

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension

Trying to run my iOS widget that is a "Today" extension. Every time i try to add it to the notification center, i keep getting the message "Terminating since there is no System App

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Im trying to make an extension that has a tableview in it

Comment: Some code or project settings might help

Comment: this issue also appears on v6.3.2 *randomly*.

Comment: occurs for me only on the iPhone 6

Answer (score 2):

In your project settings look for a setting that says "Launch Screen File" and remove anything so it is blank then clean and build.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem - Are you using swift? Commenting out the "init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?)" function as suggested in this response fixed it for me:
[iOS 8 Beta Today extension widget not showing in a Swift app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074691/ios-8-beta-today-extension-widget-not-showing-in-a-swift-app)

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to this issue with Swift in Xcode 6 - Beta 5.  The error just seemed to appear randomly, and restarting Xcode fixed it.

Comment: Can this be added as comment instead?

Comment: I'm new around here. Did I just commit the ultimate crime?

Comment: No, that's a legitimate answer. It's fair game to post "restart the app", especially if it works.