# iOS 8 Beta Today extension widget not showing in a Swift app?

Tags: swift, ios8, ios-app-extension

Today extension doesn't show up in a Swift app, but it does in a Objective C app.

What I did was to add a UILabel with some content on the storyboard for the swift and objective c apps.

It showed up when I ran the Objective C app, but not when I executed the Swift app.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I experienced the same thing.  Gave up on swift and played in Obj-c instead.  Maybe B2?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can comment out the supplied init method.

```c
//    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
//        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
//        // Custom initialization
//    }
```

This will allow your extension to run properly. The issue seems to be caused by differing initializer behavior between Swift and Objective-C. Removing the above initializer will inherit all of the required initializers from the superclass.

Found that solution [on the apple developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/974438#974438) for your reference.

*Note: You may have to `Clean and Build` your project after doing this before the changes will have any effect*

The extension is actually *crashing*, with an error like:

```
fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(coder:)' for class 'com_blabla_blabla_MyTodayExtension.TodayViewController'
```

This indicates that another option would be to implement:

```c
init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    // Custom initialization here
}
```

if you want to retain the ability to do custom initialization.

Comment: This is a very important answer. Lots of people having trouble using Swift to make widgets for iOS 8, and this quick-fix does the trick.

Comment: @n00neimp0rtant This is also covered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24036440/2446155)

Answer (score 3):

> An app extension target must include the arm64 (iOS) or x86_64
>   architecture (OS X) in its Architectures build settings.

See [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html)

Comment: Thank you! This definitely solves my problem. Apparently Xcode doesn't include the appropriate 64-bit architecture automatically, as stated in the documentation. Everyting worked fine in the simulator, but on my device (5s) the widget's body wouldn't appear.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode6 is beta and this is a bug with it, you will have to wait for a new release.

Comment: Are you sure, because I didn't find this in the release notes. So this means , I won't be able to work with extensions with Swift right now?

Comment: Im pretty sure its a bug, a lot of people have run into it, you will just have to wait for the next beta update, it is beta software after all!

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me was that the extension's deployment target was set to a different version than my app's target. You should confirm the extension's target is set appropriately because it may target a different version.

[image]