# Today Extension not working

Tags: ios8, ios-app-extension

I have some issues in Today Extensions on iOS8. I tried debugging using the Xcode Debugger and by putting nslogs. There is no logic in my code as well. For some reason:

1. The widget is not displaying any data (its only working for Hello World Label)
2. Debugging is not working, it doesn't reach any break points.  Is there any specific way to debug extensions?

Here is my code snippet

```
@implementation TodayViewController{
    NSArray *localList;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    [self loadList];

    [self setPreferredContentSize:self.tableView.frame.size];

    NSLog(@"inside awake from nib");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   NSLog(@"inside view did load");
}

-(void)loadList{
    NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:5];
    [mutableArray addObject:@"asdjasdj"];
    [mutableArray addObject:@"qowiepqiw"];
    [mutableArray addObject:@"qoqwoei"];
    [mutableArray addObject:@"pqoiweoqi"];
    [mutableArray addObject:@"lkdsflk"];
    [mutableArray addObject:@"kdjlkaj"];

    localList = [mutableArray copy];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   return [localList count];
} 

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"WidgetCell"];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    [label setText:[localList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]];
    [[cell contentView]addSubview:label];

    return cell; 
}
```

Comment: Any luck guys?? Even I'm having the same issue :(

Comment: I have the same issue. It doesn't seem to call any of the code I have in my class. Probably a bug.

Comment: found the solution @ http://stackoverflow.com/a/24345960/1746370 Hope it helps

Comment: My temporary solution is restarting my phone everytime I want to debug.  Obviously not a good fix, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug the extension, you need to manually attach the widget to the debugger.

From the Xcode menu "Debug" -> "Attach to process" -> "your extension bundle id"

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way in which i can get the make the debugger attached when the application is launched like it happens for the main app target?

Comment: Not at the moment. Apple will look to do this in the next iteration of XCode is the latest word I have heard.

Comment: @AnkushAgrawal From the release note of Xcode 6 beta 3, it seems apple has fixed this problem. I haven't got a chance to verify this though.

Answer (score 3):

Write this

```
[self setPreferredContentSize:self.tableView.frame.size];
```

before loading any subview (*tableview* or *label*), and I write these in `viewDidLoad`. It works for me.

Comment: in swift, `preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 600)`

apparently width is uncontrollable and can thus be set to 0.

Answer (score 2):

If the widget is not displaying, you can also try rebooting the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that the phone is unlocked if you're running it on a device. At least for me running the widget target won't unlock the phone but it works just fine if I do it myself.