# Crash log :- "Terminating since there is no system app"

Tags: ios, objective-c

I m working an app.running on iOS 8.3 and XCode 6.3.1 Since  my app randomly crashes (generally not long after starting to run) and my iphone displays a black screen with the white apple logo. Like the boot up screen but only for a few seconds. Then the iphone goes back to the locked screen.

it,s working fine in simulator but getting  crash on running in iphone .

thanks in advance.

Comment: at the time of app start  or a particular viewcontoller load .when crash is coming

Comment: It,s take time , fetching some data from core data after insertion . half and more then half data load and then crash. And working of data manupulation in background threads.

Comment: Do you use custom implementation like init(nibName nibNameOrNil: ... ?

Comment: @user3344236 yes  i use custom implementaion .

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074691/ios-8-beta-today-extension-widget-not-showing-in-a-swift-app

Comment: @user3344236 I checked , but didn't  help full .

Comment: Ok, what you got in device logs when you running app on device, via XCode ? Perhaps something there should give a clue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80762/discussion-between-garry-and-user3344236).

Comment: I'm getting the same stuff with my app, but it only happens on iPhone SE running iOS 10.1.1. This is no normal crash, says my senses. Did you find out the cause of your problems? The crash flow looks very similar for me, the app rotates for a second then goes to lock screen. A normal crash should end up on home screen. Looks like something in iOS crashed - I think this is normally called the springboard.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

In your project settings look for a setting that says "Launch Screen File" and remove anything so it is blank then clean and build.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you have problem same me.

In this issue i bought cause image size is very big. then run build will crash this issue.

If every one get massage this issue try check image size by try remove image if can run build success it's mean image you is oversize should reduce image.

thankyou.