# Terminating since there is no system app?

Tags: ios, xcode6

Has anyone been experiencing the error message "Terminating since there is no system app" lately in XCode?

I have a CoreAudio app (built with The Amazing Audio Engine framework) running on iOS 8.1 and XCode 6.1. Since XCode 6.1 (or/and iOS 8.1) my app randomly crashes (generally not long after starting to run) and my iPad displays a black screen with the white apple logo. Like the boot up screen but only for a few seconds. Then the ipad goes back to the locked screen.

The log windows says : "Terminating since there is no system app". No very helpful ;^(

Anyone is having the same issue? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extension in iOS8 - Terminating since there is no system app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24064147/extension-in-ios8-terminating-since-there-is-no-system-app)

Answer (score 2):

That error message is just telling you that iOS stopped running. So obviously the app is no longer running and won't be able to again until the iPad finishes rebooting. As far as what causes the crash you need to do some more exploring. Definitely turn on exception breakpoints to see if you can catch the crash before the whole device crashes. Another thing to keep in mind is that the debugger, for whatever reason, will not work if you have distribution profiles installed. If you have an app with an included push profile, for example, it will always crash shortly after launch because the debugger takes it down with it.

Comment: Thanks. In my experience, I usually reboot my ipad and things get back to normal.

Comment: I'm having same issue and I'm not able to log the crash so can you tell me please this issue happens ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the entry view, and see if it works with other views.
If yes, then check if you loaded big size images or other resources in the original entry view. Sometimes this can cause memory insufficient issue at apple devices.

Answer (score 1):

this also shows up when changing the iOS language setting.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when installing the Xcode 8.0 beta. I restarted my machine and the problem went away.