# XPC connection interrupted. [Common] Terminating since there is no system app for iOS 10

Tags: objective-c, ios10

I have created one application in which I have schedule 64 UNNotificationRequest for iOS 10.

Notifications fired at correct time. But sometimes my device os is reboot and fetches above error.

Comment: More details are required to help.

Comment: I click on start button in the application and scheduled 64 userNotificatios for iOS 10. I received that at scheduled interval but sometimes iOS is reboot and I get above error on console. I didn't get what is reason of getting that error.

Comment: Code and such, maybe sample project.

Comment: I created for loop unto 64 limit and added one by one userNotificatios in it using userNotification framework.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26847178/1457385 plus the link in the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing RND on this I found answer on apple site is we can't schedule local notification more than 30 at a time.This solve my problem.